# Reload and display a tableView whitch is based on a view in the MainStoryboard

Tags: ios5, tableview, uistoryboard, reloaddata, setneedsdisplay

I'm searching for a solution for the upper since last week, but I found no solution on the internet. So I thought I'll get help here.

Now to may question: I have a MainStoryboard and in it a ViewController with a View. On that view I've put a tableView.
ViewController.h

```
IBOutlet UITableView *tableView
//on bottom
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;
```

ViewController.m I've synthesized it and now I would like to reload and display it while the view is shown.
The following things I tested with no result: `[tableView reloadData]; [self.tableView reloadData]; [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];`
And if I used `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` I've got the following Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternatlInconsistencyExeption', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle <...> (loaded)' with name 'ViewController'' *** First thow call stack: (...) terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Thats right, there is no NIB file, because I've used the Storyboard. Well have anyone an idea?

Only thing I've found is, that if I reload the view by a button on the view within the Storyboard, the tableView gets reloaded - complete reload - but that is no solution.

Can I do something for that in `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboard *)segue sender:(id)sender`? That method I'm using only for an popover till now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually connected the IBOutlet up in Interface Builder?

Xcode should tell you if it's connected: it'll show a little circle in the margin of your header file, and if that circle has a dot inside it it's connected, if not then it isn't.

[image: Dots]

To connect an outlet in Interface Builder, right-drag from the thing with the outlet (i.e. your view controller) to the thing you want to connect it to (your table), and when you let go it gives you a menu of possible outlets to choose from.

Comment: Hello Amy Worrall, thanks for that fast answer! Yes, I've did it.

Comment: Any other idea? I've thought about to go back to *.xib instead of storyboard, but that would be sad ;(

Comment: A few questions: is your table view one of the new Storyboard static tableviews, or is it a traditional dynamic one? If the latter, do you have the data source and delegate connected up?

Comment: It is set to "Content: Dynamic prototypes". Yes, I've connected up the delegate an dataSource. It already is showing content. But it only refreshes when starting the app.